# How to create a new object in Python Django, if it does not exist in two other classes?

Tags: python, django

There are two classes in a model- Task and TaskArchives. i need to create a new task if it does not already exist in both Task andTaskArchives. i've tried checking the DoesNotExist exception with an and clause. but it doesn't work. could someone please suggest a different method ??

```
for event in events:
        try:
            obj = Task.objects.get(task_id = event['id'])
            obj_archive = TaskArchive.objects.get(task_id = event['id'])

        except Task.DoesNotExist and TaskArchive.DoesNotExist:
            obj = Task.objects.create(
            task_id = event['id'],
            title = event['summary'],
            created_by = User.objects.get(email=event['creator']['email']),
            status = "upcoming",
            due_date = event['start']['dateTime']
            )
```

Thanks in advance,
Reenu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the QuerySet's [`exists()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists) function. It returns `True` if the QuerySet contains any results, and `False` if not.

So, for the example above I would write:

```
if not Task.objects.filter(task_id = event['id']).exists() and
   not TaskArchive.objects.filter(task_id = event['id']).exists:
    # no object satisfying query exists
else:
    # at least one object satisfying query exists
```

Comment: i just solved it by setting and incrementing a flag for both the exceptions. but your answer is the simplest way. Thank you.